# Same query with different execution time in mongodb

Tags: mongodb

I've executed one and the same query several times and the execution time differ from about a second to more than 20 seconds.

MongoDB version is 3.2.10.

Below is the output from explain method of a fast and a slow query.

Fast query:

```
{
  "executionTimeMillis": 309,
  "allPlansExecution": [
    {
      "shardName": "sh001-rs",
      "allPlans": []
    }
  ],
  "totalKeysExamined": 18478,
  "nReturned": 15096,
  "executionStages": {
    "executionTimeMillis": 309,
    "shards": [
      {
        "shardName": "sh001-rs",
        "executionSuccess": true,
        "executionStages": {
          "needYield": 0,
          "docsExamined": 18378,
          "saveState": 144,
          "restoreState": 144,
          "isEOF": 1,
          "inputStage": {
            "saveState": 144,
            "isEOF": 1,
            "seenInvalidated": 0,
            "keysExamined": 18478,
            "nReturned": 18378,
            "invalidates": 0,
            "keyPattern": {
              "_id": 1
            },
            "isUnique": true,
            "needTime": 99,
            "isMultiKey": false,
            "executionTimeMillisEstimate": 30,
            "dupsTested": 0,
            "restoreState": 144,
            "direction": "forward",
            "indexName": "_id_",
            "isSparse": false,
            "advanced": 18378,
            "stage": "IXSCAN",
            "dupsDropped": 0,
            "needYield": 0,
            "isPartial": false,
            "indexBounds": {
              "_id": []
            },
            "works": 18478,
            "indexVersion": 1
          },
          "nReturned": 15096,
          "needTime": 3381,
          "filter": {
            "available": {
              "$gt": 0
            }
          },
          "executionTimeMillisEstimate": 180,
          "alreadyHasObj": 0,
          "invalidates": 0,
          "works": 18478,
          "advanced": 15096,
          "stage": "FETCH"
        }
      }
    ],
    "nReturned": 15096,
    "totalKeysExamined": 18478,
    "totalChildMillis": 251,
    "totalDocsExamined": 18378,
    "stage": "SINGLE_SHARD"
  },
  "totalDocsExamined": 18378
}
```

Slow query:

```
{
  "executionTimeMillis": 16139,
  "allPlansExecution": [
    {
      "shardName": "sh001-rs",
      "allPlans": []
    }
  ],
  "totalKeysExamined": 18478,
  "nReturned": 15096,
  "executionStages": {
    "executionTimeMillis": 16139,
    "shards": [
      {
        "shardName": "sh001-rs",
        "executionSuccess": true,
        "executionStages": {
          "needYield": 0,
          "docsExamined": 18378,
          "saveState": 677,
          "restoreState": 677,
          "isEOF": 1,
          "inputStage": {
            "saveState": 677,
            "isEOF": 1,
            "seenInvalidated": 0,
            "keysExamined": 18478,
            "nReturned": 18378,
            "invalidates": 0,
            "keyPattern": {
              "_id": 1
            },
            "isUnique": true,
            "needTime": 99,
            "isMultiKey": false,
            "executionTimeMillisEstimate": 270,
            "dupsTested": 0,
            "restoreState": 677,
            "direction": "forward",
            "indexName": "_id_",
            "isSparse": false,
            "advanced": 18378,
            "stage": "IXSCAN",
            "dupsDropped": 0,
            "needYield": 0,
            "isPartial": false,
            "indexBounds": {
              "_id": []
            },
            "works": 18478,
            "indexVersion": 1
          },
          "nReturned": 15096,
          "needTime": 3381,
          "filter": {
            "available": {
              "$gt": 0
            }
          },
          "executionTimeMillisEstimate": 14518,
          "alreadyHasObj": 0,
          "invalidates": 0,
          "works": 18478,
          "advanced": 15096,
          "stage": "FETCH"
        }
      }
    ],
    "nReturned": 15096,
    "totalKeysExamined": 18478,
    "totalChildMillis": 16076,
    "totalDocsExamined": 18378,
    "stage": "SINGLE_SHARD"
  },
  "totalDocsExamined": 18378
}
```

The results from db.stats():

```
{
    "raw" : {
        "sh001-rs/host101-prod:27017,host102-prod:27018" : {

            "db" : "records",
            "collections" : 2,
            "objects" : 124335,
            "avgObjSize" : 48253.87085695902,
            "dataSize" : 5999645033,
            "storageSize" : 5008375808,
            "numExtents" : 0,
            "indexes" : 17,
            "indexSize" : 17960960,
            "ok" : 1,
            "$gleStats" : {
                "lastOpTime" : Timestamp(0, 0),
                "electionId" : ObjectId("7fffffff0000000000000018")
            }
        },
        "sh002-rs/host101-prod:27018,host102-prod:27017" : {

            "db" : "records",
            "collections" : 2,
            "objects" : 100643,
            "avgObjSize" : 58044.42780918693,
            "dataSize" : 5841765348,
            "storageSize" : 4884041728,
            "numExtents" : 0,
            "indexes" : 17,
            "indexSize" : 13737984,
            "ok" : 1,
            "$gleStats" : {
                "lastOpTime" : Timestamp(0, 0),
                "electionId" : ObjectId("7fffffff0000000000000002")
            }
        },
        "sh003-rs/host103-prod:27017,host104-prod:27018" : {

            "db" : "records",
            "collections" : 2,
            "objects" : 191296,
            "avgObjSize" : 31400.14176459518,
            "dataSize" : 6006721519,
            "storageSize" : 5967814656,
            "numExtents" : 0,
            "indexes" : 17,
            "indexSize" : 32346112,
            "ok" : 1,
            "$gleStats" : {
                "lastOpTime" : Timestamp(0, 0),
                "electionId" : ObjectId("7fffffff0000000000000012")
            }
        },
        "sh004-rs/host103-prod:27018,host104-prod:27017" : {

            "db" : "records",
            "collections" : 2,
            "objects" : 100904,
            "avgObjSize" : 58444.951716482996,
            "dataSize" : 5897329408,
            "storageSize" : 5684531200,
            "numExtents" : 0,
            "indexes" : 17,
            "indexSize" : 14114816,
            "ok" : 1,
            "$gleStats" : {
                "lastOpTime" : Timestamp(0, 0),
                "electionId" : ObjectId("7fffffff000000000000000c")
            }
        },
        "sh005-rs/host105-prod:27017,host106-prod:27018" : {

            "db" : "records",
            "collections" : 16,
            "objects" : 851626,
            "avgObjSize" : 10900.204212882181,
            "dataSize" : 9282897313,
            "storageSize" : 7225233408,
            "numExtents" : 0,
            "indexes" : 43,
            "indexSize" : 31690752,
            "ok" : 1,
            "$gleStats" : {
                "lastOpTime" : Timestamp(0, 0),
                "electionId" : ObjectId("7fffffff000000000000000e")
            }
        },
        "sh006-rs/host105-prod:27018,host106-prod:27017" : {

            "db" : "records",
            "collections" : 2,
            "objects" : 100946,
            "avgObjSize" : 58688.667386523484,
            "dataSize" : 5924386218,
            "storageSize" : 7723163648,
            "numExtents" : 0,
            "indexes" : 17,
            "indexSize" : 13565952,
            "ok" : 1,
            "$gleStats" : {
                "lastOpTime" : Timestamp(0, 0),
                "electionId" : ObjectId("7fffffff0000000000000059")
            }
        },
        "sh007-rs/host107-prod:27017,host108-prod:27018" : {

            "db" : "records",
            "collections" : 2,
            "objects" : 100988,
            "avgObjSize" : 58563.519497366025,
            "dataSize" : 5914212707,
            "storageSize" : 4643889152,
            "numExtents" : 0,
            "indexes" : 17,
            "indexSize" : 14073856,
            "ok" : 1,
            "$gleStats" : {
                "lastOpTime" : Timestamp(0, 0),
                "electionId" : ObjectId("7fffffff000000000000000c")
            }
        },
        "sh008-rs/host107-prod:27018,host108-prod:27017" : {

            "db" : "records",
            "collections" : 2,
            "objects" : 100747,
            "avgObjSize" : 58695.07362005817,
            "dataSize" : 5913352582,
            "storageSize" : 4877357056,
            "numExtents" : 0,
            "indexes" : 17,
            "indexSize" : 13676544,
            "ok" : 1,
            "$gleStats" : {
                "lastOpTime" : Timestamp(0, 0),
                "electionId" : ObjectId("7fffffff0000000000000002")
            }
        },
        "sh009-rs/host109-prod:27017,host110-prod:27018" : {

            "db" : "records",
            "collections" : 4,
            "objects" : 69101,
            "avgObjSize" : 152884.28821580007,
            "dataSize" : 10564457200,
            "storageSize" : 16441020352,
            "numExtents" : 32,
            "indexes" : 17,
            "indexSize" : 26171376,
            "fileSize" : 19251855360,
            "nsSizeMB" : 16,
            "extentFreeList" : {
                "num" : 0,
                "totalSize" : 0
            },
            "dataFileVersion" : {
                "major" : 4,
                "minor" : 22
            },
            "ok" : 1,
            "$gleStats" : {
                "lastOpTime" : Timestamp(0, 0),
                "electionId" : ObjectId("7fffffff0000000000000000")
            }
        },
        "sh010-rs/host110-prod:27017,host113-prod:27018" : {

            "db" : "records",
            "collections" : 4,
            "objects" : 69148,
            "avgObjSize" : 152176.07311852838,
            "dataSize" : 10522671104,
            "storageSize" : 16439971776,
            "numExtents" : 32,
            "indexes" : 17,
            "indexSize" : 26269488,
            "fileSize" : 19251855360,
            "nsSizeMB" : 16,
            "extentFreeList" : {
                "num" : 0,
                "totalSize" : 0
            },
            "dataFileVersion" : {
                "major" : 4,
                "minor" : 22
            },
            "ok" : 1,
            "$gleStats" : {
                "lastOpTime" : Timestamp(0, 0),
                "electionId" : ObjectId("7fffffff0000000000000002")
            }
        },
        "sh011-rs/host109-prod:27018,host111-prod:27017" : {

            "db" : "records",
            "collections" : 2,
            "objects" : 77687,
            "avgObjSize" : 75111.53102835738,
            "dataSize" : 5835189511,
            "storageSize" : 5171572736,
            "numExtents" : 0,
            "indexes" : 17,
            "indexSize" : 9543680,
            "ok" : 1,
            "$gleStats" : {
                "lastOpTime" : Timestamp(0, 0),
                "electionId" : ObjectId("7fffffff0000000000000002")
            }
        },
        "sh012-rs/host114-prod:27017,host115-prod:27018" : {

            "db" : "records",
            "collections" : 4,
            "objects" : 91151,
            "avgObjSize" : 115459.23068315213,
            "dataSize" : 10524224336,
            "storageSize" : 16454213568,
            "numExtents" : 32,
            "indexes" : 17,
            "indexSize" : 42793184,
            "fileSize" : 19251855360,
            "nsSizeMB" : 16,
            "extentFreeList" : {
                "num" : 0,
                "totalSize" : 0
            },
            "dataFileVersion" : {
                "major" : 4,
                "minor" : 22
            },
            "ok" : 1,
            "$gleStats" : {
                "lastOpTime" : Timestamp(0, 0),
                "electionId" : ObjectId("7fffffff0000000000000028")
            }
        },
        "sh013-rs/host114-prod:27018,host115-prod:27017" : {

            "db" : "records",
            "collections" : 2,
            "objects" : 99992,
            "avgObjSize" : 58494.27406192495,
            "dataSize" : 5848959452,
            "storageSize" : 6180712448,
            "numExtents" : 0,
            "indexes" : 17,
            "indexSize" : 13615104,
            "ok" : 1,
            "$gleStats" : {
                "lastOpTime" : Timestamp(0, 0),
                "electionId" : ObjectId("7fffffff00000000000000a5")
            }
        },
        "sh014-rs/host111-prod:27018,host113-prod:27017" : {

            "db" : "records",
            "collections" : 4,
            "objects" : 91498,
            "avgObjSize" : 114842.1660801329,
            "dataSize" : 10507828512,
            "storageSize" : 16454213568,
            "numExtents" : 32,
            "indexes" : 17,
            "indexSize" : 42646016,
            "fileSize" : 19251855360,
            "nsSizeMB" : 16,
            "extentFreeList" : {
                "num" : 0,
                "totalSize" : 0
            },
            "dataFileVersion" : {
                "major" : 4,
                "minor" : 22
            },
            "ok" : 1,
            "$gleStats" : {
                "lastOpTime" : Timestamp(0, 0),
                "electionId" : ObjectId("7fffffff0000000000000004")
            }
        }
    },
    "objects" : 2170062,
    "avgObjSize" : 48193.523844940835,
    "dataSize" : 104583640243,
    "storageSize" : 123156111104,
    "numExtents" : 128,
    "indexes" : 264,
    "indexSize" : 312205824,
    "fileSize" : 77007421440,
    "extentFreeList" : {
        "num" : 0,
        "totalSize" : 0
    },
    "ok" : 1
}
```

I've noticed that it is mainly the number of "saveState" and  "restoreState" that differ. What could be the possible reason for this execution time variance?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How much RAM is available for your MongoDB server and does this also happen when you execute the query within the same period of time?

Comment: RAM is 128G and it happens randomly, if for example execute 10 queries one after another, one or two are slow.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if this is sufficient as an answer for you, but it is possible to get different numbers when running the same query. 
In depends on:

- how many other operations are happening at the moment on your server
- are the requested documents in memory (RAM) in this case the index.

[Here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/explain-results/#explain.executionStats) you can also find the documentation for the output of your `explain()`

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
Those queries were executed one after another with no delay, so the number of other operations should not be very different.
And there is enough memory to fit the index, which is not too big, about 20MB.

Comment: Well it's not just queries, it could be disk IO when syncing data. You can try increasing your profiling level https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.setProfilingLevel/ and also read this https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/administration/analyzing-mongodb-performance/#database-profiling

Comment: The only difference between the fast and the slow query that database profiler shows, besides execution time, is the bigger number of "numYield" and "acquireCount".

Comment: One last thing that you can do is `db.stats()` and paste the results on your question

Comment: I've added the results from db.stats().